# Sending a file via POST in Angular2 + .NET

Tags: .net, angular

I'm trying to send a chosen file via post. However, the File method on the backend isn't executed.

This is the frontend code:

```
 clicked(event: EventTarget) {
        let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
        let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
        let fileCount: number = target.files.length;
        let formData = new FormData();
        if (fileCount > 0) { // a file was selected
            for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
                formData.append('file[]', target.files.item(i));
            }
            this.http.post("http://localhost:1234/file", formData);
        }
    }
```

This is the backend code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("file")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void File(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string path = "~/UploadedFiles/" + file.FileName;
    file.SaveAs(path);
    _transactionService.ImportFile(path);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure thst is the correct url?  Can you hit the server api from postman or dimilsr client?  I would have expected an web api route to have controller name and 'api' in the url

Comment: Works fine with postman.